# Polynomials with real coefficients in NTL

Tags: c++, fft, multiplication, ntl

Does anyone know if the NTL library supports polynomials with real number coefficients, such as from the NTL classes RR or xdouble or just regular `C++` floats?

I'm wanting to do polynomial multiplication for polynomials with real coefficients and would like if there was a class "`RR_X`" (or something similar) like the `ZZ_X` and `ZZ_pX` classes that supports FFT polynomial multiplication.

Comment: Provide more info like what did you try and what is not working. Also provide a working code snippet to allow others to review and answer better.

Comment: At the moment (v.11.0.0), NTL does not support real coefficients in polynomials.